# Sitecore context returns Master instead of Web database

Tags: site-configuration

My Site configuration looks like this:

```
<site name="sitename" patch:after="site[@name='web_module'] targetHostName="HostName" 
              database="web" 
              virtualFolder="/" 
              physicalFolder="/" 
              rootPath="RootPath" 
              startItem="/Home" 
              dictionaryPath="DictionaryPath" 
              dictionaryAutoCreate="false" 
              placeholderSettingsRoot="PlaceholderSettingsRootPath"
              domain="extranet" 
              allowDebug="true" 
              cacheHtml="true" 
              htmlCacheSize="50MB" 
              registryCacheSize="0" 
              viewStateCacheSize="0" 
              xslCacheSize="25MB" 
              filteredItemsCacheSize="10MB" 
              enablePreview="true" 
              enableWebEdit="true" 
              enableDebugger="true" 
              disableClientData="false" 
              cacheRenderingParameters="true" 
              renderingParametersCacheSize="10MB" 
              formsRoot="formsRootGUID"
              loginPage="/login"
              enableItemLanguageFallback="true" />
```

However if I use the `Sitecore.Context.Database` to get the context to get items, it returns master instead of web in `sc_mode=normal`.

```
Sitecore.Data.Database context = Sitecore.Context.Database;
```

Why is it so and what could possibly go wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: And where do you use this code? Is it a controller? Some background code? Have you tried with `?sc_mode=normal parameter`?

Comment: this is being used in a private method called from the controller. Yup, for SC_mode=normal it returns Master instead of Web

Comment: And what returns `Sitecore.Context.Site.Name` and `Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["database"]`?

Comment: Is the above config from `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx`? Else check using that and make sure you do not have the LIveMode.config enabled.

Comment: Thanks @jammykam. No, this was not from showconfig.aspx and after seeing your comment, I went to showconfig.aspx and the database was master there.After digging in further, I figured out the database was patched to master in a different config devsettings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not uncommon for developers or certain servers to be configured to run in "Live Mode", by patching the `database` attribute to `master`. By using this setting it allows you to view the site without needing to publish or put items through any workflows.

If the database attribute has been patched then `Sitecore.Context.Database` will return that value, i.e. `master`, even in normal mode.

In a default instance of Sitecore, a sample config patch file named `LiveMode.config.example` is provided for the `website` site, for example:

```
<sites>
  <site name="website">
    <patch:attribute name="database">master</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="filterItems">true</patch:attribute>
    <patch:attribute name="enableWorkflow">true</patch:attribute>
  </site>
</sites>
```

You should verify your site configuration by browsing to `/sitecore/admin/showconfig.aspx` which will show the final configuration after all the config patches have been processed and applied.

If the setting is different then it must have been patched by another config file. Often the config will show an extra attribute such as `patch:source="LiveMode.config"` which will tell you where it was patched from otherwise search the contents of the files in the `Include` folder.

Answer (score 3):

It means that you're not in the scope of the site you added in your question or you're inside a `DatabaseSwitcher` context.

Looking at the config (especially empty virtual and physical folder), I'm guessing that your site may be added after another site which accepts same urls.

Check `Sitecore.Context.Site.Name` and `Sitecore.Context.Site.Properties["database"]` to see which site context is used in your method.

Comment: Thanks! After seeing @jammykam's comment, I went to showconfig.aspx and the database was master there.After digging in further, I figured out the database was patched to master in a different config - devsettings